# Display the username of a user who disconnects from the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, socket.io

I'm trying to display a message when a user disconnects from the server. It currently works in that it will display the message to all connected users. However, if I try and use the user variable to display which user has disconnected, it shows the connected clients' name to themselves, rather than the actual user who left. I've tried a couple of things but can't get it to work, and this is what I've come up with.
In the browser, the following code will display, "undefined has left the chat", when someone disconnects.

How can I correct this to display the actual user's name?

In the script.js:

```
var user = user;
if (!user) {
  user = prompt('Please choose a username:');
  if (!user) {
    alert('Your name has been set to "Anonymous"');
  } else {
      alert('Your name has been set to "'+ user +'"');
  } 
}

socket.emit('user disconnected', {
    user: user
  });

socket.on('user disconnected', (data) => {
      $('.chat').append(data.user + " has left the chat");
    });
```

In the server.js:

```
server(socket('disconnect', ctx => { console.log(ctx.data); ctx.io.emit('user disconnected', ctx.data); }));
```

Additionally, once the user disconnects, 'transport close' is posted to the console, and I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are close. I have written the below code for your example. Practically it will be a lot more different than this like adding a database or using some session storage.

Below is server.js

```
const app = require('http').createServer(handler);
const io = require('socket.io')(app);
const fs = require('fs');

const userIdMap = {};

app.listen(3000);

function handler(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/test.html', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading test.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  var handshakeData = socket.request;

  const userName = handshakeData._query['user'];
  console.log('userName', userName);
  if (!userName || userName === 'null') {
    console.log('Disconnecting...');
    return socket.disconnect();
  }

  const onLeave = () => {
    console.log('disconnecting', userIdMap[socket.id]);
    socket.broadcast.emit(
      'userDisconnect',
      `${userIdMap[socket.id]} is disconnected`
    );
    delete userIdMap[socket.id];
  };

  userIdMap[socket.id] = handshakeData._query['user'];
  console.log('userIdMap', userIdMap);

  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });

  socket.on('disconnect', onLeave);
  socket.on('close', onLeave);
});
```

In the above code,

- I have maintained a map of user name and socket.id which is unique for every connection.
- The user name is stored in a map - `userIdMap`. Note that how I have read userName from the query.
- I am using `socket.broadcast.emit()` to broadcast to all client in case someone leaves(tab close or reload).
- we are broadcasting on `userDisconnect` event in case someone leaves. Client-side have to add a listener so as to get notified for this.

And below is the client implementation:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var user = user;
  if (!user) {
    user = prompt('Please choose a username:');
    if (!user) {
      alert('Your name has been set to "Anonymous"');
    } else {
      alert('Your name has been set to "' + user + '"');
    }
  }

  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000', { query: `user=${user}` });

  socket.on('connect', (data) => {
    var handshakeData = socket.request;
    console.log('connect', data);
  });

  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log('news', data);
  });

  socket.on('userDisconnect', (data) => alert(data));
</script>
```

Hopes this helps :)
Happy coding